# looking up values and adding to data structure

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a .tsv file of text data, named [world_bank_indicators](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uaxptvphcg0ue4o/world_bank_indicators.txt).

I have another tsv file, which contains additional information that I need to append to a list item in my script.  that file is named [world_bank_regions](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1wkds4rps4qct9r/world_bank_regions.txt)

So far, I have code (thanks to some of the good people on this site) that filters the data that I need from world bank indicators and writes it as a 2D list to the variable mylist.  additionally, I have code that reads in the second file as a dictionary. code is below:

```
from math import log
import csv
import re

#filehandles for spreadsheets
fhand=open("world_bank_indicators.txt", "rU")
fhand2=open("world_bank_regions.txt", "rU")

#csv reader objects for files
reader=csv.reader(fhand, dialect="excel", delimiter="\t")
reader2=csv.reader(fhand2, dialect="excel", delimiter="\t")

#empty list for appending data into
#appending into this will create a 2d list, or "a list OF lists"
mylist=list()
mylist2=list()

mydict=dict()

myset=set()
newset=set()


#filters data by iterating over each row in the reader object
#note that this IGNORES headers.  This will need to be appended later
for row in reader:
    if row[1]=="7/1/2000" or row[1]=="7/1/2010":
        #plug columns into specific variables, for easier coding
        #replaces "," with empty space for columns that need to be converted to floats
        name=row[0]
        date=row[1]
        pop=row[9].replace(",",'')
        mobile=row[4].replace(",",'')
        health=row[6]
        internet=row[5]
        gdp=row[19].replace(",",'')

        #only appends rows that have COMPLETE rows of data
        if name != '' and date != '' and pop != '' and mobile != '' and health != '' and internet != '' and gdp != '':
            #declare calculated variables
            mobcap=(float(mobile)/float(pop))
            gdplog=log(float(gdp))
            healthlog=log(float(health))

            #re-declare variables as strings, rounds decimal points to 5th place
            #this could have been done once in above step, merely re-coded here for easier reading
            mobcap=str(round(mobcap, 5))
            gdplog=str(round(gdplog, 5))
            healthlog=str(round(healthlog,5))


            #put all columns into 2d list (list of lists)
            newrow=[name, date, pop, mobile, health, internet, gdp, mobcap, gdplog, healthlog]

            mylist.append(newrow)
            myset.add(name)

for row in reader2:
    mydict[row[2]]=row[0]
```

what I need to do now is 
1. read the country name from the mylist variable, 
2.look up that string in the key value of mydict, and 
3. append the value of that key back to mylist.

I'm totally stumped on how to do this.

should I make both data structures dictionaries?  I still wouldn't know how to execute the above steps.

thanks for any insights.

Comment: Just a comment on readability.  I would have found this a lot easier to read if the variable 'fhand' had been called 'bank_indicator_file', and if 'reader' had been called 'bank_indicators'.   The fact that the first thing is "file handle" and the second is a "csv reader" has no relevance at the places later where they are being used.   Indeed, you may change the implementation of reading the file later, but still have a list that you iterate.  What is relevant is "what does this thing represent in my program" IMHO it would be better to name things in a way that answers that question...

Comment: thanks, that's a good suggestion for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "append the value of that key back to mylist".   Do you mean, append the value we got from mydict to the list that contains the country name we used to look it up?   Or do you mean to append that value from mydict to mylist itself?

The latter would be a strange thing to do, since mylist is a list of lists, wheras the value we are talking about ("row[0]") is a string.   I can't intuit why we would append some strings to a list of lists, even though this is what your description says to do.    So I'm assuming the former :)

Let's assume that your mylist is actually called "indicators", and mydict is called "region_info"

```
for indicator in indicators:
    try:
      indicator.append(region_info[indicator[0]])
    except:
      print "there is no region info for country name %s" % indicator[0]
```

Another comment on readability.  I think that the elements of mylist would be better being dicts than lists.   I would do this:

```
newrow={"country_name" : name, 
        "date": date, 
        "population": pop,
        #... etc
```

because then when you *use* these things, you can use them by name instead of number, which will be more readable:

```
for indicator in indicators:
    try:
      indicator["region_info"] = region_info[indicator["country_name"]]
    except:
      print "there is no region info for country name %s" % indicator["country_name"]
```

Comment: so, we're appending the string using "indicator[0]" as the key value for region_info...don't know why that was so hard to figure out.

Comment: Heh - yes.  Basically, the code does what your sentence said to do (or at least, what it would have said to do, if it said it clearly ;) ).    Coding is nice like that - once you can say what you want to do, you can code it.    However, I do recommend that you go the dictionary way, not the append to the list way.  Because then when you read the code it tells you what it is doing.   I can't understate the importance (IMHO) of the code saying clearly what it is doing, reading like speech as much as possible.   Faced with the append version, one has to ask "WTF is indicator[0]??"   :)

Comment: ...wheras the dictionary way says "The region info for an indicator is obtained by looking up the country name of the indicator in the region info".   Well... that's obvious isn't it :)

Comment: Gotcha.  Appreciate the insight. "scattered thinking" has definitely been my biggest problem so far